# Does anybody has idea bout Time-series data de-trending using quadratic polynomial trend?

Tags: r, time-series, nonlinear-regression, excel

I understand how first order differences can be used to remove a linear trend in a time series data set.

But how can we detrend a time series with a quadratic trend?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I wanted to know how can we detrend timeseries data using non linear regression (i have read in one paper mentioning quadratic polynomial trend method to detrend crop yield trend but details have not been given).

Comment: @NirmalManiDahal 1st order for removing a linear trend, 2nd order for removing a quadratic trend, 3rd order differencing for removing a cubic trend, etc...intuitively, the best way to think of differencing is as the discrete time equivalent of [differentiation/calculating derivatives](http://web.mit.edu/wwmath/calculus/differentiation/polynomials.html#:~:text=The%20derivative%20of%20the%20sum,multiplied%20by%20the%20same%20constant.) - in order to go from a polynomial to a constant value, you have to differentiate the function the same number of time as the order of the polynomial.

Comment: @SkanderH. I had used first diff to detrend crop yield and climate for regression. But the effects of climate seems to low. So i read "detrending using some non-linear regression may be better (such as local regression)". I am confused on this. I read a paper mentioning quadratic polynomial trend method to detrend crop yield trend. Is it the same with non linear regression (local regression)? Also first difference (lag 1) removes linear trend. Is it removes quadratic trend if used difference method with lag 2?

Comment: ""detrending using some non-linear regression may be better (such as local regression)" This might be possible, but it would be tricky to say the least. May I ask why you want to detrend the signal in the first place? Understanding that will help you better figure out which method you want to use.

Comment: @SkanderH. I got the detrending idea from the first diff method and I used it for regressing climate variables (CV) with crop yield. But the CV effect is lower which means effect of Non CV is higher. So first diff may be not applicable for detrending in my case. In the mean time i got to know about this "detrending using some non-linear regression may be better (such as local regression)" and use it to see my results difference. Your query on "May I ask why you want to detrend the signal in the first place?". May be i didin't get it but my problem is as mentioned in this comment section.